# Apresentar resultados centrados em uma tabela

Tags: html, angularjs, table

Quero apresentar os dados através de um `ng-repeat` numa tabela, ele coloca os dados corretos mas sempre à esquerda da célula da tabela, já tentei adicionar `<td valign="middle">` mas sem sucesso.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Dia</th>
                    <th>Mes</th>
                    <th>Ano</th>
                    <th>Media</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="result in jsonResult">
                    <td valign="middle">{{result.Dia}}</td>
                    <td valign="middle">{{result.Mes}}</td>
                    <td valign="middle">{{result.Ano}}</td>
                    <td valign="middle">{{result.Media}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só incluir o estilo:

td {height: 50px; width:50px;}

```css
td {height: 50px; width:50px;}

#cssTable td {text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">Text</td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table border="1" id="cssTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```